# Is there a way to know which application is producing sound(audio output) in ubuntu, through code?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, sound, pulseaudio

I want to write a code which detects the applications that are producing sound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list all applications producing sound by using `pacmd list-sink-inputs`. You'll get a list of indexes with indented details per source. Then you'll want to look at the "state" field. If it is "RUNNING", then it's playing sound. Directly below, you'll find "sink", which is which output it's playing to. Underneath, you'll find a "properties" field which includes other details, such as "application.name".

I don't know if there are any nice libraries available, but parsing this data shouldn't be too complicated. Perhaps you'll even find some nice regexes out there.

Comment: Can you please name some libraries?